# How to convert "Set functions" such as removeAll and addAll from Java to C++? Can it be done using erase or insert?

Tags: java, c++, code-conversion

I've been trying to convert a Java code to C++ and I stumbled upon this part of a code which repeats a couple of times.

```
//JAVA
TreeSet<String> currentState = new TreeSet<String>();
TreeSet<String> allTransitions = new TreeSet<String>();
       .
       .
       .
currentState.addAll(allTransitions);
       .
       .
       .
currentState.removeAll(allTransitions);
```

I tried to achieve the same in C++ by typing the following code:

```
//C++
set<string> currentState;
set<string> allTransitions;
       .
       .
       .
currentState.insert(allTransitions);
       .
       .
       .
currentState.erase(allTransitions);
```

When I try compiling this code I get a lot of errors so I'm wondering is it even possible to replicate the same functions from Java to C++ easily or is there another way to add sets to eachother and remove them.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The first one need the begin and end iterator like this:

```
currentState.insert(allTransitions.begin(), allTransitions.end());
```

The second is most easily performed using a for loop if operating on `std::set` (which you can turn into a function):

```
for(const auto& t: allTransitions)
  currentState.erase(t);
```

If you where to operate on a sorted `std::vector/deque/list` etc you could have utilized the set functions for the second operation (`std::set_difference/set_intersection` etc)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Sorry to bother you but I have one little question regarding this conversion. In java the function is ```if(allTransitions.contains("#") && allTransitions.size() != 1){allTransitions.remove("#");} ``` How would I create this in C++? I tried by ```if((allTransitions.find("#") != allTransitions.end()) && allTransitions.size() != 1){allTransitions.erase("#);} ``` I don't think this is correct though,

Comment: The `insert()` function needs three parameters, the first being the insertion position (what you usually want here is `currentState.end()` to emulate Java behavior)

Answer (score 0):

Following Viktor's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60908794/7976805), you could use [`std::set_difference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference) to remove elements (but loop is much cleaner alternative)

```
std::set<std::string> tempCurrentState;
std::set_difference(currentState.begin(), currentState.end(), 
                    allTransitions.begin(), allTransitions.end(),
                    std::inserter(tempCurrentState, tempCurrentState.end()));

currentState = tempCurrentState;
```

It might or mignt not be slightly faster (`O(n + k)` time complexity rather than `O(n*log(k))`), but there's additional copy. Profiling would be required to truly determine which one is faster. Loop is certainly more readable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Sorry for taking your time but I have one little question regarding this conversion. In java the function is ```if(allTransitions.contains("#") && allTransitions.size() != 1){allTransitions.remove("#");}``` How would I create this in C++? I tried by ```if((allTransitions.find("#") != allTransitions.end()) && allTransitions.size() != 1){allTransitions.erase("#);}``` I don't think this is correct though

Comment: @Jamess11 Please, one question at a time.  If you have another question, open a new post.